# How can I transfer widget with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I'm developing a demo app where, I have to show an animation when I scroll-up and scroll-down, also the option layout should appear and hide.
When I scroll down, the layout start hiding at some point depending on scrolled height.
I don't know what should I use for this animation.
please let me know this.

[Here is the link](https://cloud.protopie.io/p/c22468e6b4)

Comment: Means it's a progress bar when scrolled up and load more items from API at that time diaplay this progress animation? your queation need more cliarity.

Comment: not about progress bar. when I scroll down, the 664 items layout start hiding at some point. exactly the layout moves upwards. And when I scroll up at some point, it moves downwards, and the I can see it.

Comment: it seems you're trying to achieve [scrolling behavior](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/10980/coordinatorlayout-scrolling-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeking is quite easily possible. You just need to have a base layout as `CoordinatorLayout` with `AppBarLayout` and then bind the scrolling behavior with underlying `RecyclerView` or `NestedScrollView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout  
    ...>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        .../>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Possible follow a [post here](https://android.jlelse.eu/scrolling-behavior-for-appbars-in-android-41aff9c5c468)

An extended guide about all such behaviors [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout)

These will help you better understand and customise your requirements. There was a similar view we had to develop 2 years back, there were some custom view scroll handling that we had to capture to make it work.

But these resources should be a good start for you. Good Luck!